# Confusing probability problems based on product rule and combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am going thru probability exercise. Faced first problem:

> **Book Q1.** Ten tickets are numbered 1,2,3,...,10. Six tickets are selected at random one at a time **with replacement**. What is the probability the largest number appearing on the selected tickets is 7?

**My logic:** if one of six tickets should be 7, the $\color{red}{\text{remaining 5}}$ can be any of 1 to 7, so it should be $7^5$.

But turns out that the given solution is $\frac{7^6-6^6}{10^6}$.

**My Q1.** Though I understood the logic behind $\frac{7^6-6^6}{10^6}$, I was wondering **what is exact logical mistake with $7^5$?** I guessed that $7^5$ completely ignores what should be 6th ticket, it only puts restriction on 5 tickets. Is it like that?

Then I came across similar but more involved problem, with significant difference from above one that it performs action without replacement:

> **Book Q2.** Three numbers are chosen at random **without replacement** from (1,2,3,...,10). What is the probability that the minimum number is 3 or the maximum number is 7?

**My logic:** Noticing that this is without replacement, I guessed the solution should be 
$$
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
\text{selections with}\\ 
\text{minimum}\\ 
\text{number is 3} 
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix} 
\text{selections with}\\ 
\text{maximum}\\ 
\text{number is 7} 
\end{pmatrix} 
-
\begin{pmatrix} 
\text{selections with}\\ 
\text{maximum}\\ 
\text{number is 7}\\ 
\text{and minimum}\\ 
\text{number is 3} 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

$$=
\frac{
\overbrace{(\binom{8}{3}-\binom{7}{3})}^{\text{#selections with min 3}}
+
\overbrace{(\binom{7}{3}-\binom{6}{3})}^{\text{#selections with max 7}}
-
\overbrace{3\times {^3P_3}}^{\text{#selections with max 7 and min 3}}
}
{\binom{10}{3}
}
$$
But the book solutions says:

> P(minimum 3) or P(maximum 7)
>
> P(minimum 3) $=\frac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{21}{120}$
>
> P(max 7) $=\frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{15}{120}$
>
> Thus the solution is $\frac{11}{40}$

**My Q2.** How even by books logic the solution $\frac{11}{40}$ is achieved. I am unable to understand it as I find the explanation insufficient.

**My Q3.** If book Q2 answer is correct then why for book Q1 solution is not $7^5$ which is what I initially guessed (because the only difference being with / without replacement, the logic of getting $\color{red}{\text{remaining m}}$ stuffs out n should remain same)?

**My Q4.** If we make first question without replacement, will the solution be $\frac{\binom{7}{6}-\binom{6}{6}}{\binom{10}{6}}$?

**My Q5.** What will be the solution if we make book Q2 with replacement?

**My Q6.** Where my logic for solution to Book's Q2 is wrong?

Comment: Your logic for $7^5$ appears to specify that the first element is a $7$. As in, you say that there is a $7$, and then you choose $5$ elements from a set of $7$, with replacement.  In reality, the $7$ need not appear in the first slot.  That's why the book has a different answer.

Comment: But then why books says $P(min 3) = \frac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}$? I think, in taking $\binom{7}{2}$, book applies same logic as mine in case of $7^5$. *Remaining 2 should come from 7 without replacement $\binom{7}{2}$* vs *Remaining 5 should come from 7 with replacement $7^5$*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your calculation of $7^5$ you are in effect assuming that the first ticket is a $7$; $7^5$ is then the number of ways to choose the remaining $5$ tickets so that none of them is greater than $7$. Since any of the six tickets might end up being the only one to show a $7$, you might try multiplying your count by $6$ to get $6\cdot 7^5$. However, you would then be overcounting: the sequence of tickets $7,1,3,7,3,5$, for instance, would be counted once for the first $7$ and once again for the second $7$. It’s possible to compute the correct value by breaking the sequences into cases according to the number of $7$s, but it’s much simpler just to start with the $7^6$ sequences that don’t contain a number larger than $7$ and subtract the $6^6$ that don’t contain a $7$.

For your second question, note that $\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k+1}=\binom{n}k$; this is just a rearrangement of Pascal’s identity. Thus, your $\binom83-\binom73$, for instance, is equal to the book’s $\binom72$, and your $\binom73-\binom63$ is equal to the book’s $\binom62$. The reasoning that allows the book to go directly to $\binom72$ and $\binom62$ is this: we can form a set with a maximum of $7$ be picking $2$ numbers from the $6$-member set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, since we know that the remaining number will be a $7$, and we can form a set with a minimum of $3$ by picking $2$ numbers from the $7$-member set $\{4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, since we know that the remaining number will be a $3$. Now $\frac{21}{120}+\frac{15}{120}=\frac7{40}+\frac5{40}=\frac{12}{40}$, and from that we must subtract the probability of getting both a maximum of $7$ and a minimum of $3$. But that’s easy: the remaining number must be $4,5$, or $6$, so there are just $3$ possible sets of $3$ numbers, and the probability of getting one is $\frac3{120}=\frac1{40}$. The final probability is therefore $\frac{12}{40}-\frac1{40}=\frac{11}{40}$.

The problem with your $3\times{^3P_3}$, which I assume is $3\cdot3!=18$, is that it takes the order of the draw into account, while every other part of your calculation merely counts unordered sets of numbers. You can do it either way, but you have to be consistent. Without taking order into account there are, as we just saw, only $3$ sets with minimum $3$ and maximum $7$, not $18$; there are $18$ sequences in which those sets can be drawn, however, $6$ for each. Alternatively, you can multiply each of the other two terms and the denominator by $3!$ to take order into account in all of them.

For your third question, with versus without replacement isn’t the only difference, if you calculate the second result using sets of numbers rather than sequences (as you mostly did): there’s also the difference in whether you take the order of draws into account. In the first question you have to do so; in the second, you don’t (and it’s easier not to).

The answer to your fourth question is *yes*, though you can simplify the numerator to $\binom65$: you know that you must have the $7$, so you need only count the number of ways to pick the remaining $5$ numbers from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

**Correction.** For the second question *with* replacement there are $8^3$ sequences of three numbers that do not include either $1$ or $2$ and therefore have a minimum that is at least $3$. $7^3$ of these do not include $3$, so there are $8^3-7^3$ sequences that have a minimum of $3$. Similar reasoning shows that there are $7^3-6^3$ sequences that have a maximum of $7$, so as a first approximation we have

$$(8^3-7^3)+(7^3-6^3)=8^3-6^3$$

sequences with a minimum of $3$ or a maximum of $7$. However, that counts twice those sequences that have both a minimum of $3$ *and* a maximum of $7$. It’s easy to count these more or less by hand: if there are two $3$s and a $7$, the $7$ can be in any one of $3$ places, so there are $3$ such sequences. Similarly, there are $3$ sequences with two $7$s and a $3$. If there is one $3$, one $7$, and one intermediate number, there are $3$ choices of intermediate number, and $3!=6$ orders for each set of three numbers, for a total of $18$ more sequences. Thus, there are $3+3+18=24$ sequences with a minimum of $3$ *and* a maximum of $7$, and the final count is

$$8^3-6^3-18=278\;.$$

Since there are $10^3$ sequences altogether, the probability is $0.278$.

Comment: I think for the last bit you answered the question of drawing three numbers with max 7 _and_ min 3 instead of max 7 _or_ min 3.

Comment: @Eric: No, I subtracted those from $\{3,4,5,6,7\}$ containing *neither* $3$ nor $7$; that leaves the ones that have one or the other or both.

Comment: +1 for *However, you would then be overcounting: the sequence of tickets $7,1,3,7,3,5$, for instance, would be counted once for the first $7$ and once again for the second 7.*

Comment: +1 for pointing out how I am mixing up ordered and unordered count in case of ${^3P_3}$

Comment: However: *Since any of the six tickets might end up being the only one to show a $7$, you might try multiplying your count by $7$ to get $7^6$.* I think here you meant *multiplying count by $6$ to get $7^5\times 6$*. Is it?

Comment: Also you said I have to take order in account in 1st question but not in 2nd question. But while solving 1st question without replacement, we solved it as if order is not concerned, thus arriving at numerator $=\binom{7}{6}-\binom{6}{6}=\binom{6}{5}$. But if the order is taken into account, this will be I guess $$\underbrace{^6P_5}_{\text{selecting  5 tickets out of 6 in some order}}\times \underbrace{6}_{\text{putting 7 in one of 6 places}}$$ Similarly denominator will change to $^{10}P_6...$

Comment: $...$I guess whether to take order in account should be stated explicitly. Is it like that? Or is it without replacement implicitly dictates unordered selection?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you require all of the three chosen numbers to be in $\{3,4,5,6,7\}$, which is not a requirement in the question.

Comment: @Mahesha999: Yes, I meant to multiply by $6$ in the first paragraph. And yes, if you take order into account in the first question without replacement, your analysis for the numerator is one of several correct ones. Without replacement may or may not allow you to look at unordered selections: it depends on exactly what is being counted. When you *can* look at unordered selections, it’s usually a little easier to do so.

Comment: @Eric: See corrected version. It appears that in my original I forgot at that point what I had already counted and was thinking that I’d already eliminated anything with an entry out of the range from $3$ to $7$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have enumerated all possible variations of the above problems and their solutions for reference purpose as a separeate answer to this question. **(1)** Can you please confirm if all solutions are correct especially the 5th one. **(2)** Also did I missed any variation? **(3)** Is it just coincidence that the solution to both 5th and 6th problem in answer is same 0.275

Answer (score 1):

Addressing your **Q1**, the difference between the answer you gave and the answer that the book gives is that your solution assumes that a specific selection is 7.  That is, $\frac{7^5}{10^6}$ is the probability that *a fixed ticket* is 7 and the other five take values from 1 to 7 while the books solution just assumes that *at least* one of the tickets is 7.

**Q2** The second problem is much different as there is no order on the sets of chosen numbers.  Note that $\binom{8}{3}-\binom{7}{3}=\binom{7}{2}$  and $\binom{7}{3}-\binom{6}{3}=\binom{7}{2}$, so that part of your answer is consistent with the book solution--though the logic that the book uses might be a tad bit more straightforward.  In each of the above cases, the book solution fixes the given number and then chooses two other numbers at random from the allowed set (either $\{$greater than 3$\}$ or $\{$less than 7$\}$).  Using this type of reasoning we can quickly enumerate the number of choices with max 7 and min 3: two of the choices are fixed and there are only three possibilities for the third choice.  Hence the solution is
$$
\frac{\binom{7}{2}+\binom{6}{2}-3}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{11}{40}.
$$

For your **Q3**, again, the implied order in the first problem makes it easy to accidentally specify an order during the solution process (and as a result get the wrong answer).  Note that your solution for the second problem was not necessarily wrong (I don't know what $3\times^3P_3$ means), you just used a different method than the book.

For your **Q4** you are correct.  This is the same thing as $$\frac{\binom{7}{5}}{\binom{10}{6}}.$$

**Q5**  The answer would be
$$
\frac{(8^3-7^3)+(7^3-6^3)-5}{10^3}.
$$
Let me know if you have any questions about how I arrived at the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the actual answers already given, I am putting different possible scenarios and there solutions here for reference.

1. Selecting six out of {1,2,3,...,10} **with replacement**. Probability of largest selected number is 7 = ?

   **Sol.** 
   $$
   \overbrace
   {\frac{7^6-6^6}{10^6}}
   ^{
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \text{no. of ways of selecting any six out of {1,..,7}} \\
   \text{removing those not containing 7}\\
   \text{i.e. those six from {1,..,6}}\\
   \end{pmatrix}
   }=0.070993$$
2. Selecting six out of {1,2,3,...,10} **without replacement** while **taking order of selection into account**. Probability of largest selected number is 7 = ?

   **Sol.** 
   $$
   \frac{
   \overbrace{\binom{7}{6}}
   ^{\begin{pmatrix}
   \text{no. of ways to} \\
   \text{select six from {1,..,7}} \\
   \text{without considering} \\
   \text{order} \\
   \end{pmatrix}}
   -
   \overbrace{\binom{6}{6}}
   ^{\begin{pmatrix}
   \text{no. of ways to} \\
   \text{select six from {1,..,6}} \\
   \text{without considering} \\
   \text{order} \\
   \end{pmatrix}}
   }{
   \binom{10}{6}
   }=
   \frac{
   \overbrace{\binom{6}{5}}
   ^{\begin{pmatrix}
   \text{selecting six from {1,..,7}} \\
   \text{with 7 as max reduces to} \\
   \text{selecting 5 from {1,..,6}} \\
   \text{since you know you must} \\
   \text{have 7} \\
   \end{pmatrix}}
   }{\binom{10}{6}}=\frac{1}{35}=0.028571
   $$
3. Selecting six out of {1,2,3,...,10} **without replacement** while **not taking order of selection into account**. Probability of largest selected number is 7 = ?

   **Sol.**
   $$
   \frac
   {\overbrace
   {^6P_5}
   ^{
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \text{no. of ways to select five} \\
   \text{out of {1,..,6} while} \\
   \text{considering order} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   }
   \times
   \overbrace
   {6}
   ^{
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \text{putting 7} \\
   \text{in one of 6 places} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   }
   }{^{10}P_6}
   $$
4. Selecting three out of {1,2,3,...,10} **with replacement**. Probability of largest selected number is 7 and smallest is 3 = ?

   **Sol.**
   $$\frac{(8^3-7^3)=(7^3-6^3)-18}{10^3}=0.278$$
   For details, see correction in Brian Scott's solution.
5. Selecting three out of {1,2,3,...,10} **without replacement** while **taking order of selection into account**. Probability of largest selected number is 7 and smallest is 3 = ?

   **Sol.**
   $$
   \frac
   {\overbrace
   {^7P_2\times 3}
   ^{
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \text{no. of ways to select two} \\
   \text{out of {4,..,10}}  and \\
   \text{put 3 in any of three places} \\
   \text{making 3 min number among} \\
   \text{three selected} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   }
   +
   \overbrace
   {^6P_2\times 3}
   ^{
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \text{no. of ways to select two} \\
   \text{out of {1,..,6} put 7}  and \\
   \text{put 7 in any of three places} \\
   \text{making 7 max number among} \\
   \text{three selected} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   }
   -
   \overbrace
   {^3P_3 \times 3}
   ^{
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \text{Selecting 3 tickets with both} \\
   \text{min 3 and max 7:} \\
   \text{first select any one of} \\
   \text{4,5 or 6,then perform} \\
   ^3P_3\text{ arrangements with the} \\
   \text{selected number,3 & 7} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   }
   }{^{10}P_3}
   = \frac{198}{720} = 0.275
   $$
6. Selecting three out of {1,2,3,...,10} **without replacement** while **not taking order of selection into account**. Probability of largest selected number is 7 and smallest is 3 = ?

   **Sol.**
   $$
   \frac
   {\overbrace
   {\binom{8}{3}-\binom{7}{3}}
   ^{
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \text{no. of selections} \\
   \text{with 3 as minimum} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   }
   +
   \overbrace
   {\binom{7}{3}-\binom{6}{3}}
   ^{
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \text{no. of selections} \\
   \text{with 7 as maximum} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   }
   -
   \overbrace
   {3}
   ^{
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \text{no. of selections with both} \\
   \text{3 as min & 7 as max:} \\
   \text{{3,7,4},{3,7,5},{3,7,6}} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   }
   }{\binom{10}{3}}
   =\frac{\binom{7}{3}+\binom{6}{2}-3}{\binom{6}{2}}
   =\frac{11}{40}
   =0.275
   $$